# Dask diagnostics - progress bar with map_partition / delayed

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask, dask-distributed

I am using the distributed scheduler and distributed progressbar.
Is there a way of having the progress bar work for Dataframe.map_partition or delayed? I assume the lack of futures is what causes the bar not to work. If I change my code to `client.submit` the progressbar does work.

- Code looks like this:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from distributed import Client
from distributed.diagnostics.progressbar import progress

client = Client("tcp://....")
...
ddf = dd.read_parquet("...")
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(..)
progress(ddf)  # no futures to pass
dask.compute(ddf)
```

- Alternative with dask.delayed does not work either:

```
delayed = [dask.deplayed(myfunc)(ddf.get_partition(i)) for i in range(ddf.npartitions)]
progress(delayed)
dask.compute(*delayed)
```

- Client.submit does produce a working progress bar, but code execution fails and I haven't managed to debug it yet.

```
futures = [client.submit(myfunc, ddf.get_partition(i)) for i in range(ddf.npartitions)]
progress(futures)
dask.compute(*futures)
```

> Is there a way to get the progress bar (or a report of tasks completed vs total) working for map_partitions or dask.delayed ?

- Full code example with delayed:

```
import dask
import npumpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from distributed import Client
from distributed.diagnostics.progressbar import progress
import time

cl = Client("tcp://10.0.2.15:8786")

def wait(df):
    print("Received chunk")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("finish")

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)

futures = [dask.delayed(wait)(ddf.get_partition(i)) for i in range(ddf.npartitions)]
progress(futures)
dask.compute(*futures)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, `progress` is intended to work with futures or collections that contain futures. You don't need submit a big list of futures to use it, though:

```
ddf = ddf.map_partitions(..)
fut = client.compute(ddf)
progress(fut)
# wait on fut, call fut.result() or continue
```

Also don't forget: the distributed scheduler that you are using, even if on a single machine only, comes with a diagnostics dashboard that contains the same information. Usually this is at `http://localhost:8787`, and you can access from any browser.

Comment: I need to use ProgressBar, so I can provide updates through the application update stream. I tested the above approach with the example code but submit gives am error:
TypeError: First input to submit must be a callable function
Did this work in the past? version 2.30.0

Comment: That's a big miss in the docs, no? From a recent tutorial by Coiled from September this year, it still states: "You can use Dask’s built-in Progress Bar (see Fig 2) to visualize the progress on any get() or compute() calls." It doesn't mention anywhere that it doesn't work with `delayed`.